# What is the difference between Hold and Restart of DPD action in strongswan IPsec?

Tags: ipsec, strongswan, dpd

**Question**

When I tested IPsec DPD on Router, I found that both **Hold** and **Restart** reestablished VPN connection after **dpdtimeout**, so I didn't understand the difference between them

I found the relevant explanation in strongswan's document, but I couldn't understand the real difference

**strongswan Doc - Hold**

Hold installs a trap policy, which will catch matching traffic and tries to re-negotiate the connection on demand.

**strongswan Doc - Restart**

Restart will immediately trigger an attempt to re-negotiate the connection.

**strongswan - DPD timeout**

dpdtimeout = 150s

defines the timeout interval, after which all connections to a peer are deleted in case of inactivity.
This only applies to IKEv1, in IKEv2 the default retransmission timeout applies, as every exchange is used to detect dead peers.

**Thank**

Comment: https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ConnSection

Comment: I use IKEv1 to set up ipsec tunnel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as the documentation states: "restart" forces the renegotiation immediately, while "hold" waits for a specific traffic before doing so.